# Changing a file on the server using a local windows app

Tags: c#, excel, file, portal

I am writing an automation to update the contents on an excel sheet(in c#) present on our server. Our server has various portals and has different credentials. How could I fetch the file on my portal to my local computer to make some changes to it.

Comment: the server has each instance for every user ex. A has A.xls and B has B.xls , both have there own credentials to login to.

Answer (score 1):

Is your computer on a domain with the server? If so...

Run as a user who has access and manipulate it via UNC paths just like normal paths... for example you would load @"\Servername\share\file.xls" instead of @"C:\path\file.xls".